# Synchronous NodeJS batch job

Tags: node.js, async-await

I'm trying to write a batch script that will

1. Read XMLs from a directory
2. Parse each XML and find a value to use for DB(database) Lookup
3. Use the parsed value to DB lookup additional metadata
4. Populate XML with the metadata retrieved from DB lookup (step 4)
5. Write updated XML to complete directory
6. Close DB connection

The issue I'm running into is that I cannot control the code execution order so that I can close the DB connection at the end of the script. If I attempt to close the connection, I  get a 'connection undefined' error. Below is my code for reference. Is there a good way to accomplish something like this in NodeJs, or should I look at doing this in Java or some other language?

```
enter code here
'use strict';
let fs = require('fs');
let xml2js = require('xml2js');
const oracledb = require('oracledb');
const dbConfig = require('./dbconfig.js');



function pad(number, length) 
  {

   var str = '' + number;
    while (str.length < length) 
     {
       str = '0' + str;
     }

      return str;
  }

async function run() {



  try {
        // Get a non-pooled connection




       let connection;

        if (!connection) 
         {
           connection = await oracledb.getConnection(dbConfig);
           console.log('Connection was successful!');
         }

         let directory = "EDI_XMLS";
         let dirBuf = Buffer.from(directory);
         //var f = 0;
         let files = fs.readdirSync(directory);
           console.log(files);




         for (let f = 0; f < files.length; f++) 
          {
            let parser = new xml2js.Parser();
            var xml_json_data = "";
            // read the file
            await fs.readFile(directory + "/" + files[f], async function(err, data)             { 
                 // parse the file
                await parser.parseString(data, async function(err, result) {

                let results;

                var line_count = result.page.GLLines[0].GLLine.length;
                console.dir('Invoice: ' + result.page.InvoiceNumber[0]);
                console.dir('Line Total: ' + line_count);
                console.log('File: ' + f);

                try 
                  { // Lookup Data
                      results = await connection.execute('SELECT BUSINESS_UNIT, OPERATING_UNIT, DEPTID,PRODUCT,a.effdt FROM SYSADM.PS_A_NSS_SHPTO_ACC@FDEV a where(a.a_ship_to_customer = :shipTo) order by a.effdt 
                      desc',[pad(result.page.VoucherDescription[0], 10)], {
                        maxRows: 2
                    });
                    console.log(results.metaData);
                    console.log(results.rows);
                  } 
                catch (err) 
                  {
                    console.error(err);
                  }



                 for (let i = 0; i < line_count; i++) // Populate data
                  {
                     result.page.GLLines[0].GLLine[i].GLBU[0] = results.rows[0][0];
                     result.page.GLLines[0].GLLine[i].OpUnit[0] = results.rows[0[1];
                     result.page.GLLines[0].GLLine[i].Department[0] = results.rows[0][2];
                     result.page.GLLines[0].GLLine[i].Product[0] = results.rows[0][3];
                  }

                   // Write to File
                   var builder = new xml2js.Builder();
                   var xml = builder.buildObject(result);
                   await fs.writeFile("complete/" + files[f], xml, function(err, data) {
                    if (err) console.log(err);
                    console.log("successfully written our update xml to file");
                    console.dir('BUs: ' + JSON.stringify(result.page));
                 }); //end write
               }); //end parser
             }); //end readfile
       console.log('End');
      } // async for

     } 
    catch (err)
    {
       console.error(err);
    } 

  finally 
    {
      await connection.close();
      console.log('Finally Done');
    }




 }




run();



console.log('completely Done');
```

Comment: Please format your code example properly.   
Why are you awaiting `fs.readFile` and `parser.parseString`? They aren't awaitable, they use callbacks.   
Also a for-loop doesn't "await" the operations in its body so you probably should use another construct to iterate.

Comment: Hey Christian, I should have mentioned that I'm new to coding. We have some legacy scripts we are trying to convert to run on NodeJS. The legacy javascript engine runs code synchronously, so I'm trying to await the read and write actions so that we are able to run the code synchronously on NodeJS.

Comment: `await conneciton.close();` <-- typo here. regardless of how new you are to coding, if you get a "conneciton is undefined" error, it really helps to be able to notice simple typos like that on first glance.

Comment: formatting code is easy: the line containing a *starting bracket* `{` and the line containing an *ending bracket* `}` need to be indented the same number of spaces. lines of code *contained by* those brackets `{ ... }` need to be indented further than the bracket lines. as is, your code is barely readable, i haven't the slightest idea at a glance what the control flow is like.

Comment: @robbra your edit changes nothing, the problem is still a typo. this question should be closed

Comment: Even with the typo correction I still get the same error. I think it may be a scope issue. Taking a course on NodeJS this week, so hopefully, I'll be able to fix the issue on my own soon.